# Select data from pandas multiindex pivottable

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe (pivottable) with 1703 rows that looks like this:

```
Local code     Ex Code    ...  Value      
159605         FR1xx      ...  30               
159973         FR1xx      ...  50    
...
ZZC923HDV906   XYxx       ...  20
```

There are either numerical local codes (e.g. 159973) or local codes consisting of both characters and strings (e.g. ZZC923HDV906)
I'd like to select the data by the first index column (Local code). This works well for the string characters with the following code

```
pv_comb[(pv_comb.index.get_level_values("Local code") == "ZZC923HDV906")]
```

However I don't manage to select the numerical values:

```
pv_comb[(pv_comb.index.get_level_values("Local code") == 159973)]
```

This returns an empty dataframe. 
Is it possible to convert the values in the first column of the multiindex into string characters and then select the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need `''`, because your `numeric` values are `strings` - so `159973` change to `'159973'`:

```
pv_comb[(pv_comb.index.get_level_values("Local code") == '159973')]
```

If need convert some level of `MultiIndex` to `string` need create new index and then assign:

```
#if python 3 add list
new_index = list(zip(df.index.get_level_values('Local code').astype(str),
                df.index.get_level_values('Ex Code')))

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = df.index.names)
```

Also is possible there are some `whitespaces`, you can remove them by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
#change multiindex
new_index = zip(df.index.get_level_values('Local code').astype(str).str.strip(),
                df.index.get_level_values('Ex Code')
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = df.index.names)
```

Solution if many levels is first reset_problematic level, do operations and set index back. Then is possible [`sortlevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html) is necessary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Local code':[159605,159973,'ZZC923HDV906'],
                   'Ex Code':['FR1xx','FR1xx','XYxx'],
                   'Value':[30,50,20]})
pv_comb = df.set_index(['Local code','Ex Code'])
print (pv_comb)
                      Value
Local code   Ex Code       
159605       FR1xx       30
159973       FR1xx       50
ZZC923HDV906 XYxx        20

pv_comb = pv_comb.reset_index('Local code')
pv_comb['Local code'] = pv_comb['Local code'].astype(str)
pv_comb = pv_comb.set_index('Local code', append=True).swaplevel(0,1)
print (pv_comb)
                      Value
Local code   Ex Code       
159605       FR1xx       30
159973       FR1xx       50
ZZC923HDV906 XYxx        20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this, but it doesn't work. The index values seem to be objects and not strings

Comment: I've tried to convert the first index column into string type by pv_comb.index.get_level_values('Local code') = pv_comb.index.get_level_values('Local code').astype(str) but this returns "can't assign function to call" I think converting only the first index column into strings would solve my problem.. Creating an entirely new index will be complex, as there are more than ten index levels in the pivottable

Comment: Hmmm, if it is `object` it is obviously `string`. Maybe some whitespaces?

Comment: You can check it by `print (pv_comb.index.get_level_values("Local code").tolist())`